# Powershell killing processes - what's wrong with my string?

Tags: powershell

I know that working code is

```
Get-Process firefo* | Stop-Process
```

But my first guess was

```
Get-Process | findstr firefox | Stop-Process
```

It didn't work.

```
Stop-Process : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command
either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its
properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:1 char:33
+ Get-Process | findstr firefox | Stop-Process
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (   1379     317...               :PSObject) [Stop-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopProcessCommand
```

I understand that string

```
   1342     306  1228412    1279864 -1671 ...71,42  35912 firefox
```

is bad for process killing, but why?

```
PS C:\Users\adamg> Get-Process firefo*

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
   1342     306  1228412    1279864 -1671 ...71,42  35912 firefox
```

The above works just fine, even with column headers in reply.

Comment: You have to look at `Get-Help -full` for the cmdlets and look at the Input and Output object.  The dos command `findstr` only produces console text as output which cannot be used as input for a Powershell cmdlet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`findstr`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) is a commandline utility that produces string output. [`Get-Process`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849832.aspx) outputs `Process` objects, which is what [`Stop-Process`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849781.aspx) expects as input. It could also handle a list of process IDs, but it can't parse the formatted string from `findstr`.

In PowerShell you normally wouldn't use `findstr` anyway. Use a [`Where-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849715.aspx) filter instead:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.ProcessName -like '*firefox*' } | Stop-Process
```